# how to remove object from array of objects in foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I have a `users` object returned from the database that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Bob",
        "category":"admin",
        "email":"test1@test.com",
        "phone":"123456789",
        "gender":"male",
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"John",
        "category":"user",
        "email":"john@test.com",
        "phone":"123456789",
        "gender":"male",
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Jane",
        "category":"admin",
        "email":"jane@test.com",
        "phone":"123456789",
        "gender":"female",
    },
]
```

Now I want to loop through all the `users` object and remove all users whose `category` attribute is `user` so that the resulting `users` object only remains with `admin` category.

I want to do this with a foreach loop. please how do I go about this or what better ways can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you just select the 'admin' rows from the table in the first place?

Comment: No idea what happend here but someone is downvoting answers below. Check our solutions and give feedback ;)

Comment: @KarolGasienica Make a check on peoples rep, it becomes clear then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the array was in JSON format? Anyways.. I fixed your invalid JSON so you should be able to see how it's done.

```
$json = '

[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob",
    "category": "admin",
    "email": "test1@test.com",
    "phone": "123456789",
    "gender": "male"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John",
    "category": "user",
    "email": "john@test.com",
    "phone": "123456789",
    "gender": "male"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Jane",
    "category": "admin",
    "email": "jane@test.com",
    "phone": "123456789",
    "gender": "female"
}]

';

$array = json_decode($json, true); //Fixed and converted JSON into PHP Assoc Array 

foreach($array as $k=>$v) { 
    foreach ($array[$k] as $key=>$value) { 
      if ($key === "category" && $value === "user") { //If Value of 2D is equal to user and cat

          unset($array[$k]); //Delete from Array 
      }
    }  
}

var_dump($array); //Output Array
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
    [0] => array(6) {
        ["id"] => int(1)["name"] => string(3)
        "Bob" ["category"] => string(5)
        "admin" ["email"] => string(14)
        "test1@test.com" ["phone"] => string(9)
        "123456789" ["gender"] => string(4)
        "male"
    }[2] => array(6) {
        ["id"] => int(3)["name"] => string(4)
        "Jane" ["category"] => string(5)
        "admin" ["email"] => string(13)
        "jane@test.com" ["phone"] => string(9)
        "123456789" ["gender"] => string(6)
        "female"
    }
}
```

*Edit*

*As @sevavietl pointed out in the comments, if any other element of the array was called user, then this would be removed. I've changed code to now test the key (category) as well as the value. *

Comment: You can also add `$array = array_values($array)` at the end if you want to reset keys

Comment: @maestroosram That's IF the keys need resetting...he may need them for reference elsewhere in his code.

Comment: what if the `name` of an admin will be `"user"`? the element will be removed from resulting array, although the category is `"admin"`. going even further, you don't break from the inner loop after unsetting element.

Comment: @Kitson88, it will work. but why do you need this nested loop, when you just can get the category like this `$v['category']`? If it is done from concern, that there will be no key `category`, you can check this with `isset($v['category'])`.

Comment: @sevavietl You don't. I'll be honest in saying that Karol Gasienica solution is much better and less resource. What can I say...I'm still learning from mistakes everyday.

Comment: @Kitson88, as I wrote in the other comment maestroosram solution is the best. But for whatever reason, someone downvoted all answers and his answer got -1. Which is a shame. Nowadays, when you can avoid explicit loops it is usually better to do so.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the array is in json format, one line code:

```
$users = array_filter(json_decode($users), function($user) {
    return $user->category != 'user';
});
```

If it is instead already a valid php array simply remove the `json_decode()`

Comment: why do you need `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` here, if you are using only the value in the callback function?

Comment: regardless to this, this is the best-suited answer, don't know why it is downvoted. other answers just reinvent `array_filter` function.

Comment: Well, technically question asked for a `foreach` loop solution. Moreover, this method does not work in-place, which can be bad if the array is big. I doubt any of those are actual causes though, someone is carpet-downvoting answers here. Maybe that someone will post (or already has posted) his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your input looks like `JSON`, so you can use `json_decode` function to make it an array, which you can `foreach`, and you can encode (`json_encode`) it back to `JSON` if you want same output.

---

**Solution**

Code below should be useful for you:

```
<?php
// $json = output from your db
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($json_output as $user) {
    if ($user['category'] == 'admin') { // or it may be $user['category'] != 'user'
        $user_output[] = $user;
    }
}
print_r($user_output);
print_r(json_encode($user_output, true)); // if you want json output    
?>
```

---

**SQL**

You can also add in your SQL query `WHERE` statement. It might look as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE category = 'admin'
```

Of course query depends on names which you have in your table. More about `SELECT` query you can read in manuals below.

---

**Manuals**

More about used methods you can read below:

- [PHP: JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)
- [PHP: json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
- [PHP: json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

---

**Compiler online**

You can check how it works [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/445cafa99ca624cfd629538037322dd42964392a)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the category "user", you just have to get the key and make a condition for removing that category and put the category "admin" on that new array. Have a look at this:

```
$json = '
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob",
    "category": "admin",
    "email": "test1@test.com",
    "phone": "123456789",
    "gender": "male"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John",
    "category": "user",
    "email": "john@test.com",
    "phone": "123456789",
    "gender": "male"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Jane",
    "category": "admin",
    "email": "jane@test.com",
    "phone": "123456789",
    "gender": "female"
}]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($value["category"] == "admin") {
        $newArr[] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($newArr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I was shocked to notice that too, being the author of the question. But you all really helped me.